# How to use android:longclickable for implementing longclickable event for cardview?

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, android-cardview

I have a card view and I want to launch two separate events based on the fact that the view is clicked or longclicked. For click we have onclick method and android:onclick attribute. How to do this for longclick?

Comment: have you tried onLongClick?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

??? It should work.

Comment: How to implement this same thing using android:longclickable?

Comment: or in this case how to get this mView?

Comment: reference your view in you Activity/Fragment like mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_view); Here, ImageView is just an example, it could be any other view.